# Certificate pinning - public/private key for license distribution

Tags: go, openssl, certificate, x509certificate

I am trying to distribute an application - and need to add a software license to let the user use the application. I need some information to be distributed in the license regarding authorization(this works great using only public/private key)

### Pseudo steps

1. Generate the public/private key
2. Embed the public key in the code
3. Create license using encoding
4. Distribute the license file
5. Application verifies the license using the embedded public key

**6. *Problem(using certificate to verify the origin of the public key)***

### Actual steps:

1  . Generate the public/private key

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 3072
openssl rsa -in "private_key.pem -pubout -out public_key.pem
```

2 - 5 And then embed the private key in code, and read a license file like([code from here](https://github.com/adtac/go-lcns)):

```
func VerifyAndExtractPayload(publicKey *rsa.PublicKey, str string) (interface{}, error) {
    var err error

    str = strings.TrimSpace(str)

    if !strings.HasPrefix(str, header) || !strings.HasSuffix(str, footer) {
        return nil, errors.New("invalid license key")
    }

    b64 := strings.Replace(str[len(header):len(str)-len(footer)], "\n", "", -1)

    var l license
    b, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(b64)
    licenseBuffer := bytes.Buffer{}
    licenseBuffer.Write(b)
    licenseDecoder := gob.NewDecoder(&licenseBuffer)
    if err = licenseDecoder.Decode(&l); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    hashed := sha256.Sum256(l.Payload)

    if err = rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15(publicKey, crypto.SHA256, hashed[:], l.Signature); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var payload interface{}
    payloadBuffer := bytes.Buffer{}
    payloadBuffer.Write(l.Payload)
    payloadDecoder := gob.NewDecoder(&payloadBuffer)
    if err = payloadDecoder.Decode(&payload); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return payload, nil
}
```

Then I realised that maybe I should use certificate pinning, so no one can replace the public key.

Pseudo code:

1. Generate a root certificate using private key
2. Embed certificate
3. Generate license like above
4. Read public key from the certificate
5. Application verifies the license using the embedded public key

### Questions:

1. How to verify read the public key from the certificate?
2. And is the public key now verified?

Comment: If you embed the public key in the code, then you don't need to either embed or pin the certificate: the public key itself is enough. I understand the reasoning about pinning (protecting against a modification of the public key), but you have to realize that you are only "pushing the problem one step further": if the attacker can modify the public key embedded in the code, then for sure he/she can modify the certificate embedded in the code... This is the problem of any software-only protection scheme. To make the attack more difficult, consider https://github.com/burrowers/garble

Comment: Thanks and good suggestion to obfuscate.

Comment: And thanks for making it clear, that I am only "pushing the problem".